# Making a false wall with Silent Image (vs Illusory Wall)

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, illusion

Can Silent Image be used to make an illusory wall? I think it can, but there is an spell called Illusionary Wall which specifically does that. If I can use Silent Image to make an illusion of a wall, is there a compelling reason I'd ever use Illusory Wall instead?

Answer (score 8):

You are correct that *Silent Image* can create a wall. Both spells belong to the Illusion school, with the "figment" subtype, and allow a will save to disbelieve the illusion. But each spell has its advantages and limitations.

***[Silent Image](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/silent-image/)* is a temporary, cheap, and flexible illusion.**

- Consumes a level 1 spell slot.
- On the bard, magus, and wizard/sorcerer spell lists.
- Range is Long (400 ft. + 40 ft./level).
- The maximum size scales with the caster's caster level ("four 10-ft. cubes + one 10-ft. cube/level").
- Requires concentration to maintain. A caster could have only one *Silent Image* active at a time.
- If someone succeeds the will save to disbelieve the image, then they can partially see through it. According to the [rules on illusion spells](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-lllusion-Figment), it will appear translucent upon a successful will save, because the *Silent Image* is a figment.

> A successful saving throw against an illusion reveals it to be false, but a figment or phantasm remains as a translucent outline.

***[Illusory Wall](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/illusory-wall/)* is a permanent and effective illusion of a wall or similar surface.**

- Consumes a level 4 spell slot.
- On the wizard/sorcerer spell list only.
- Range is Close (25 ft. + 5 ft./2 levels).
- Illusion size is constant (1 ft. by 10 ft. by 10 ft).
- It has permanent duration, where as a *Silent Image* requires concentration to maintain. With enough castings of *Illusory Wall*, you could eventually create a permanent illusory castle!
- Unlike other figments, even if a creature succeeds the will save, the illusion is still effective. Someone may know the wall is an illusion, but they still cannot see what's on the other side!

> Although the caster can see through his illusory wall, other creatures cannot, even if they succeed at their Will save (but they do learn that it is not real).

Comment: Deleted my answer in favor of your far more complete answer.

Comment: @Miatog Sometimes other answers can be very helpful, since it may be your way of phrasing things that helps a user understand what's going on. And 2 answers is quite tolerable -- I wouldn't be saying quite this same thing if we had 10 different answers to this question. :)